# Angular Capacitor, only showing index.html

Tags: android, angular, capacitor

I have an Angular application that I want to convert in Android application thanks to Capacitor.
I installed Capacitor on my Angular Project (project with routing).
Here is the versions I use :

```
"@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^14.0.4",
"@angular/cli": "~14.0.4",
"@angular/compiler-cli": "^14.0.0",
"@capacitor/cli": "^3.6.0",
"@capacitor/android": "^3.6.0",
"@capacitor/core": "^3.6.0"
```

In my Angular.json, I have this configuration :

```
"outputPath": "dist/our_thing",
"index": "src/index.html",
"main": "src/main.ts",
```

When I created capacitor.config.ts, I set webDir to 'src', the directory where I have index.html.

In my index.html, I have this :

```
<body>
  XXXX
  <app-root></app-root>
</body>
```

And in my app.component.html, I have this :

```
YYYY
<div class="center-class">
  ZZZZ
  <app-login></app-login>
</div>
```

My problem is that when I convert the application to Android with Capacitor, on my application, I only see "XXXX" and not "YYYY" or "ZZZ" I put in my app.component. Just like if he could not find app-root in index.html. Any ideas why ?
Here is the result:

[image: Result on the android app]

On my Angular app I see everything I shall see:

[image: Result on the ANgular App on chrome]

The way my project is:

[image: architecture]

Comment: have you tried connecting the android remote debug tools to see if there is any useful info in logcat?

Comment: I am facing this problem too. The app runs well in 'ng serve' but when running npx cap open android and running via native device, it only shows raw html (without any styling). Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`webDir` should be the directory where your code is built, `src` folder contains the code before building it.
Si according to your config, it should match the `outputPath`.

Answer (score 2):

Thank you for your answer. I changed the `webDir` to `dist/XXX` to match the outputPath, and I ran `npm run build`to get that folder. It perfectly run ! Thanks !

Comment: Hi there, this should be a comment on the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72904229/5742625) instead of a separate answer. Also, while the answerer appreciates being of assistance, it's preferred to simply accept the answer instead of leaving a separate comment saying [thanks](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/330562/where-should-i-say-thank-you-on-stack-overflow) on the website. Hope this helps!